# Does certbot automatically provide encyption?

Tags: python, flask, certificate, ssl-certificate, certbot

I'm kinda new to web security.

- Does certbot automatically provide an RSA key to the server and encrypt/decrypt the whole path(SSL) of the connection (From client to server and server to client) and make it HTTPS?
- Do I simply not bother about security while developing a web app and simply make my app in HTTP and use certbot to make it secure?
- Does SSL protect against replication attacks?
- If the answer to 1 is no, please suggest a python module to encrypt the Flask app.

Thanks.

Comment: Certbot itself doesn't secure your webserver.  Certbot allows you to obtain an SSL cetificate.  You'd then typically configure your **reverse proxy** to use these certs to terminate SSL.  Plain HTTP traffic is then passed to the python app server.  Have a look at [Mozilla's SSL config generator](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/) which supports configs for a number of reverse proxies/webservers.  You can then test the live server with [Qualys SSL test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and tweak the config accordingly. Or if you CBA with all this, pick a host which handles all this stuff for you

Comment: @v25 Hey, thanks for the clarification.  but I'm still a little confused. I understand how reverse proxy works to deliver a website. So, the simple question is, Does certbot automatically encrypt the connection between the server endpoint (Reverproxy server or could be a direct server) and the client endpoint at socket layer?

Answer (score 0):

Certbot provides an SSL certificate which can be used to encrypt your connection and register you with a third party (let's encrypt). When users connect to your app, they will first verify your servers identity with let's encrypt before encrypting your connection. If you're using a server like NGINX then the easiest way to use certbot will be with the nginx certbot plugin.

HTTPS is not a security wildcard, it does provide encryption between two endpoints, preventing a host of MITM attacks but there are many threat vectors to consider. Depending on how your app works you'll still need to worry about SQL injections, malicious file uploads, remote code execution etc. HTTPS has great added security benefits absolutely, but it shouldn't replace any other security methods.

Comment: Yeah, but just tell me one thing, should I need to add aes and rsa in my flask application for security or just leave it to the certbot?